# How to load the URI programmatically in asp.net c# without redirection to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, uri

I'm opening the url link to another page and getting the url querystring link, it is opening fine but in my programming scenario it should not redirect to another page it should red in the programmatically and should give that redirected url link.

I'm fresher and learning programing ....

this is how I did :-

On page load :-

```
  string srvscope = $"https://accounts.zoho.in/oauth/v2/auth?scope={scope}&client_id={Clientid}&state=ScopeGeneration&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&access_type=offline";
             string Fullurl = srvscope;

OpenNewBrowserWindow(Fullurl, this);
```

Method :-

```
        public void OpenNewBrowserWindow(string Url, Control control)
        {
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(control, control.GetType(), "Open", "window.open('" + Url + "');", true);

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(control, control.GetType(), "Open", "window.onload('" + Url + "');", true);
        }
```

Give me the best suggestion to achieve this .

Comment: so you need to change the uri of the browser with out reloading the page? if that is correct, you need to interact with javascript,

Comment: In the page load I should load the uri that uri should not open in another window (ex window.open) that uri should load in the program only (like window.load("uri link") ===> is there any method to load the uri link in program ? like how we are opeing the uri using window.open .

sorry for my bad english.